# Como criar uma lista a partir de um retorno 'for'

Tags: python, for, csv

Preciso adicionar uma coluna em um arquivo CSV e ao tentar com o código abaixo, não retorna uma lista de listas e sim uma única lista. Podem me ajudar?

```
alunos = [
['RA', 'Nome', 'Frequencia', 'Prova_1', 'Prova_2', 'Prova_3', 'Prova_4'],
['110201', 'Antonio Carlos', '20', '6.5', '8.5', '7', '6'],
['110212', 'Ana Beatriz', '20', '7', '7', '7', '8'],
['110218', 'Carlos Vernes', '17', '7', '7', '7', '7'],
['110307', 'Francisco Cunha', '20', '9', '8.5', '8.5', '10'],]

for i, linha in enumerate(alunos): # função enumerate adiciona um índice para a lista
    # isolando o header para adicionar a última 'coluna'
    if i == 0:
        linha.append('Média')
        # print(linha)
        header = list(linha)
        # print(dados)
    else:
        linha1 = [float(x) for x in linha[3:]] #converter os itens da lista em float
        linha.append(sum(linha1)/len(linha1)) # adiciona media das notas da prova de cada aluno
        dados = list(linha) 

print(header) 
print(dados)

Output: 
['RA', 'Nome', 'Frequencia', 'Prova_1', 'Prova_2', 'Prova_3', 'Prova_4', 'Média']
['110307', 'Francisco Cunha', '20', '9', '8.5', '8.5', '10', 9.0]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ali no else, você está fazendo a atribuição e não uma append para dados. Assim toda vez que entrar no else ele vai sobrescrever o valor de dados.

Pode reparar que o output de dados é só a última linha de alunos.

Antes do for faz isso:

`dados=[]`

dentro do else:

`dados.append(list(linha))`

Comment: Cara, salvou demais. Muito obrigado! deu certinho usando como vc falou

Comment: Que bom meu amigo! Boa sorte nos estudos :D